# Error when using Pip to install plotly package on mac

Tags: python, pip, package, installation, plotly

I attempted to install plotly using the command line in terminal:

[image: Plotly install]

However, I get this massive error:

[image: Plotly error]

It goes on like that for a while. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

This command is used to update plotly package not to install it.

To install plotly use:

```
$ pip install plotly
or
$ sudo pip install plotly
or
$ easy_install plotly
```

After installing it, if you want to upgrade package then use:

```
$ pip install plotly --upgrade
```